# Central logging service with Microservices and Springboot how I can use this service as a central logging service

Tags: rest, logging, spring-boot, microservices

I have developed the RestFull webservice with SpringBoot in Microservice Architecture Envirnment and I want to use that logging service as a central logging service if anybody have idea please let me know.

Here how I can append the logs of the service where I want to consume logging service what will be in the request and response

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ELK approach :

•**Elastic Search**: Search and Analyse data .

•**LogStash**: Collect, parse and enrich data from each system

**•Kibana**: Explore and visualise your data graphically

Comment: To improve your answer maybe you can add an url of those utilities?